# https to http for all the pages with exception in drupal 7

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I have a site running on drupal. Server is https enabled. Now, I want to run all the pages in htp with exception of few pages like:

http ://www.mysite.com/

http ://www.mysite.com/tour.html

http ://www.mysite.com/contact-us.html

exception

https ://www.mysite.com/buynow.html

https ://www.mysite.com/signup.html

How can I do that with .htaccess or by installing any module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you want to redirect people to https, when they request buynow.html or signup.html. For the other pages you want them to use http. Try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/buynow.html)|(^/signup.html)
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/buynow.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/signup.html
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

### Update

New .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on

      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=protossl]
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=protossl:s]

      RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/buynow.html)|(^/signup.html)
      RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/buynow.html
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/signup.html
      RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with this code and found that https to http works but http to https does not. I have the following code included in .htaccess file. Please advice.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: @MasterMinds Did you put my code in the beginning of your .htaccess? Can you put your current htaccess into pastebin, so I could see it?

Comment: @MasterMinds Your current code redirects from non-www to www domain

Comment: yes, it's for non-www to www domain and i put your code after this. please check my .htaccess file http://pastebin.com/LMr00Zke

Comment: @MasterMinds answer updated. I am not sure about non-www to www now, check it, please.

Comment: thanks again. But it's not working. I get Error 500. Please advice.

Comment: @MasterMinds Oops, sorry, I can't test here, cause I don't have https. Try to debug yourself, using error.log

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [securepages](https://drupal.org/project/securepages) module to achieve that.

For more information about https and security in Drupal there is a [very good documentation](https://drupal.org/https-information).